# Converting a large csv to xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, csv

I have a large CSV file(30gb) with 7 columns. Would there be another format to save the file so that the size is much smaller because the first few columns have the same values for many rows?

I was thinking about an XML file type. How do I convert this large csv file to an xml file?

The solution I found involves the pandas package. But since the data is large, using pandas would not work on my 8gb ram laptop.

[image]

Comment: Xml would be larger.  To make smaller simply use ZIP to compress the file.

Comment: Do you really need all that data in memory at one time? If not, you can process the file row-by-row, and not need a lot of RAM.

Comment: I think you should probably put this in a database.

Comment: @MichaelKay how do I do that ?

Comment: how about compressing the file? gzip?

Comment: @duckman Sorry, but if you can't work out how to load a CSV file into a database, then you need to do some basic reading.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is an in-memory package, so the data must be smaller than the amount of RAM.  Can you split the original 30 GB file into a collection of smaller files, and process in pandas one at a time?  E.g., one file for each `fund_ticker`.

Dask supports out-of-memory processing for NumPy and pandas, but that is another layer of complexity.  https://dask.org

Here is info from pandas docs on scaling to large data sets: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html

Finally, is a database an option for this use case?

Comment: Can't you memory-map in pandas?